# Im writing a python program that unscrambles a given input string, permutates the unscrambled string and checks the dictionary for a common words

Tags: python, set, permutation, intersection, scramble

I've tried finding the intersection between my unscramble permutated dictionary and my dictionary words dictionary, using set but it's returning `unhashable type: list error`.

How can I fix it and what am I doing wrong?

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import permutations


class possibleWords:
    
    """
    Python program to find all possible dictionary words from a scrambled input word.
    """
    
    def __init__(self, scrambled_word):
        self.scrambled_word=scrambled_word
        self.length=len(scrambled_word)
        self.unscramble_dict=defaultdict(list)
        self.words_dict=defaultdict(list)
        
    def unscramble(self):
        """
        this method takes the scrambled word and finds all permutations from that scrambled word.
        in every iteration the permutation object Returns a list with items of the same character length. it then adds the list as the value to a dictionary with the key being the length of the items.
        """
        
    
        for r in range(2,self.length+1):
            permutation_object=permutations(self.scrambled_word, r)
            unscrambled_list=[''.join(permutation) for permutation in permutation_object]
            self.unscramble_dict[r].append(unscrambled_list)
        return self.unscramble_dict


    def english_words(self):
        """
        this method Returns a dictionary with same key as of unscramble and a value as a list with the key length
        """
        self.length=len(self.scrambled_word)
        words_list=[]
        
        with open("english_words.txt") as file_object:
            for line in file_object:
                word=line.strip()
                for r in range(2,self.length+1):
                    if len(word)==r:
                        self.words_dict[len(word)].append(word)
        return self.words_dict



instance1= possibleWords("sodwind")


def main():
"""
this function Returns A list with the common list value of the same key between unscramble and English words
"""
    unscramble_dict=instance1.unscramble()
    words_dict=instance1.english_words()
    common_word= {k: list(set(v).intersection(unscramble_dict[k])) for k, v in words_dict.items()}
    return common_word
    
print(main())
```

Comment: The last 2 lines shouldn't be inside the class definition.

Comment: You never call `self.english_words()`, so `self.words_dict` is empty.

Comment: And you never call `self.unscramble()`, so `self.unscramble_dict` is empty.

Comment: Why does `unscramble()` start at `range(2, n)`? This is not a rhetorical question, I'm not sure why we would do that.

Comment: _"Hughuteuwsgh hgdht Chu yfghg gfiurd yfghytf ughuh ugg h."_?

Comment: I just edited the code @Barmar.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman it's a mistake.